# What is the significance of the titles of the Shadowhunters series?

Tags: inspiration, shadowhunters

Some of the books in the [Shadowhunters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadowhunter_Chronicles) series by Cassandra Clare have rather poetic titles (*Queen of Air and Darkness,* *City of Heavenly Fire*, and so forth). The series themselves have some interesting titles as well (e.g. *The Mortal Instruments*).

“The Queen of Air and Darkness” is definitely a reference to [Queen Mab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Mab), but beyond that I’m unsure.

- What is the significance of the other titles in the *Dark Artifices* series?
- Is there any significance to the titles of the books in the other series as well (e.g. *Chain of Thorns, City of Glass*, and so forth)?
- Do the titles of the series have any special meaning (e.g. *The Mortal Instruments*, *The Infernal Devices*)?

By significance, I mean both *out-of-universe* (a reference to another work, a common or uncommon idiom, etc.) and *in-universe* (a reference to a character or event from within the plot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. ***The Mortal Instruments***

“Mortal instrument” is a legal term, referring to an implement capable of killing someone. For example, from the [records](https://books.google.com/books?id=FbICIb8d7FYC&pg=PA322&dq=%E2%80%9Cmortal%20instrument%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVi6yQmKbPAhXG0h4KHXNkDB8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Cmortal%20instrument%E2%80%9D&f=false) of the Cape Colony (circa 1793):

> It was decided by our law, in the event of persons having assaulted others
> actually with a **mortal instrument**, and wounded them in such a
> manner that death was the consequence; if it only appears that they
> had an intention to wound, not to kill, these have escaped the
> punishment of death.

Another possible source is Shakespeare, specifically *Julius Caesar*:

> BRUTUS:
> Since Cassius first did whet me against Caesar,
> I have not slept.
> Between the acting of a dreadful thing
> And the first motion, all the interim is
> Like a phantasma, or a hideous dream:
> The Genius and the **mortal instruments**
> Are then in council; and the state of man,
> Like to a little kingdom, suffers then
> The nature of an insurrection.

Here the “mortal instruments” are Brutus’s emotions or perhaps his body itself, which revolt against the idea of killing Caesar.

It seems likely that Cassandra Clare was familiar with both meanings.

In-universe, of course, the term refers to the three artifacts that the angel Raziel granted to the Shadowhunters: the Mortal Cup, the Mortal Sword, and the Mortal Mirror.

The meaning of most of the series titles is a bit unclear. *City of Glass* certainly refers to Idris, the city of the Shadowhunters.

> I’m going to Idris! her mind sang. I’ll see the Shadowhunter home
> country, the City of Glass. I’ll save my mother.
> <sub>*City of Glass*</sub>

On the other hand, most of the other titles take place in (say) New York, and so probably are not referring to different cities. The part after *City of* seems to refer to elements important to the book’s plot, though. For example, heavenly fire is rather important in the book of the same name.

2. ***The Infernal Devices***

In keeping with the legal theme, an “infernal device” or more commonly,  “infernal machine,” is a rarely-used term for an incendiary device, i.e. a bomb. From a [Massachusetts law](https://malegislature.gov/Search/SearchResults?Input.Keyword=infernal):

> For the purposes of this section, the term hoax device shall mean
> any device that would cause a person reasonably to believe that such
> device is an infernal machine. For the purposes of this section, the
> term infernal machine shall mean any device for endangering life or
> doing unusual damage to property, or both, by fire or explosion,
> whether or not contrived to ignite or explode automatically.

For the specific term “infernal device,” see for example [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=L7gyAQAAIAAJ&q=%E2%80%9Cinfernal%20device%E2%80%9D&dq=%E2%80%9Cinfernal%20device%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWstONnqbPAhVh44MKHaonDX04ChDoAQgfMAE).

The term might refer more broadly to any device that operates by fire, i.e *infernally*.

Of course, more colloquially “infernal device”  is an very old-fashioned way of saying a “wicked plot or scheme.”

Finally, it is worth noting that there is a book called [*Infernal Devices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infernal_Devices_(K._W._Jeter_novel)), published in 1987, which (most tellingly) is a steampunk novel that features a clockwork person, rather like Clare’s series of the same name.

In-universe, the term refers to the demon-possessed clockworks created by Axel Mortmain, which fit the term triply: they are (a) clockworks like those in the 1987 novel mentioned previous, (b) may run on steam or some similar fiery internal mechanism, and (c) are *infernal* in the sense of being possessed by entites from Hell.

As for the book names, they are quite straightforward:

- The *Clockwork Angel* is a literal device that protects Tessa.
- The *Clockwork Prince* is Mortmain.

  > “He’s not frightened at all, Anne.” The man laughed, and set the boy down on the ground, ruffling his hair. “My little clockwork prince . . .”
  > <sub>*Clockwork Prince*</sub>
- The *Clockwork Princess* is Tessa herself.

3. ***The Dark Artifices***

The title comes from Tacitus, according to an [interview](http://www.mtv.com/news/2557278/dark-artifices-cassandra-clare-interview/) with the author:

> The inspiration for the title! Okay, this is so dorky. The main
> family, the Blackthorns, of “The Dark Artifices,” have a father who is
> a classicist. He is obsessed with Greek and Roman mythology and
> history. So “The Dark Artifices” comes from “The Annals of Imperial
> Rome” by Tacitus. “It would have been less ignominious to die by the
> dark artifices of Tiberius or the fury of Caligula.” I just liked the
> phrase.

As for the titles of the individual books:

- *Lady Midnight* comes from a song by Leonard Cohen:

  > I cried, “Oh, Lady Midnight, I fear that you grow old,  the stars eat
  >
  > your body and the wind makes you cold.”

  In-book, it refers to a character from a Shadowhunter tale:

  > “Great-Aunt Marjorie gave it to me,” Tavvy said. “I like most of the stories. The one about the first parabatai is good, but some of them are sad and scary, like the one about Tobias Herondale. And the one about Lady Midnight is the saddest.”
  >
  > “Lady what?” said Cristina, leaning forward.
  >
  > “Midnight,” said Tavvy. “Like the theater you went to. I heard Mark say the rhyme and I just remembered I read it before.”
  > <sub>*Lady Midnight*</sub>
- The out-of-universe inspiration for the title *Lord of Shadows* may be Satan, who is often called the Prince of Darkness. It might also be a reference to the Wiccan God (as in God and Goddess, or Lord and Lady), who is [sometimes referred to](http://www.jesterbear.com/Wicca/FAQGodInWicca.html) as the Lord of Shadows. However, in-story, the Lord of Shadows is in fact [the Unseelie Faerie King](https://shadowhunters.fandom.com/wiki/Arawn), who is called Arawn and seems to take more inspiration from the [character of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Prydain#Characters) in *The Chronicles of Prydain* than from the Welsh mythological figure.
- As previously mentioned, *Queen of Air and Darkness* is probably a reference to Queen Mab, who is referred to by that name in various previous works of fiction, notably [*Dungeons and Dragons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fey_deities#Queen_of_Air_and_Darkness). That said, the term apparently originally referred to Morgause from *The Once and Future King*.

  > Whatever the explanation may have been, the Queen of Air and Darkness had a baby by her half-brother nine months later. It was called Mordred.

4. ***The Last Hours***

The series has a heavy dose of Dickens influence, so it is no surprise that, as noted by [this site](http://tmicanada.blogspot.com/2014/02/catch-up-on-latest-news-about-cassandra.html), the title appears to come from *Great Expectations*:

> The stones of which the strongest London buildings are made, are not
> more real, or more impossible to be displaced by your hands, than your
> presence and influence have been to me, there and everywhere, and will
> be. Estella, to **the last hours** of my life, you cannot choose but
> remain part of my character, part of the little good in me, part of
> the evil.

The titles of the books (*Chain of Thorns*, *Chain of Gold*, and *Chain of Iron*) also come from *Great Expectations*:

> Pause you who read this, and think for a moment of the long chain of
> iron or gold, of thorns or flowers, that would never have bound you,
> but for the formation of the first link on one memorable day.

5. **The Eldest Curses**

The title of the series comes from *Hamlet*, from a scene where Claudius laments having killed his brother, the former king:

> O, my offense is rank, it smells to heaven; It hath the primal eldest
> curse upon 't, A brother’s murder.

The titles reference actual books of magic within the universe of the series, so there is not much symbolism to decipher there, except to note that the juxtaposition of black, red, and white is a classic one, from being referenced in *Snow White* ("white as snow, as red as blood, and as black as the wood of
the embroidery frame") to being the colors of three of [the four humors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humorism) (with yellow) or three of the directions of [the Lakota medicine wheel](https://www.stjo.org/native-american-culture/native-american-beliefs/medicine-wheel/) (again, with yellow).

Also worth noting is that the [Book of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Dead) is a somewhat famous ancient Egyptian text, which may be referenced in the title of *The Black Volume of the Dead*.

6. ***The Wicked Powers***

This series is quite a ways off, so it’s hard to tell. Given that Clare seems to like Shakespeare, though, it could be a reference to *The Winter’s Tale*:

> PAULINA:
> Either forbear,
> Quit presently the chapel, or resolve you
> For more amazement. If you can behold it,
> I’ll make the statue move indeed, descend
> And take you by the hand; but then you’ll think–
> Which I protest against–I am assisted
> By **wicked powers**.

As [noted on the wiki](https://shadowhunters.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wicked_Powers), the in-universe significance is a reference to a rhyme about bronze protecting against wicked powers.

The titles of the individual books are not yet known.